# How to type hint a class not exposed by a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I am using a module called `pyathena` in my code, and I have a function that receives a `pyathena connection`:

```py
import pyathena

def fn(conn) -> None:
    <DO SOMETHING>

conn = pyathena.connect(s3_staging_dir=f's3://<THE_BUCKET>/', region_name=<REGION>)

fn(conn)
```

I would like to type hint the `conn` parameter of `fn`.

I know that conn is of type `pyathena.connection.Connection`, but doing

```py
def fn(conn: pyathena.connection.Connection) -> None:
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

doesn't work:
`AttributeError: module 'pyathena' has no attribute 'connection'`.

Doing

```py
from pyathena.connection import Connection

def fn(conn: Connection):
    ...
```

seems to work well, but I don't want to expose this `Connection` class in my code, other than to do the type hinting.

**Q: Is there a way to type hint this unexposed class in my code without having to import as I did above?**

Useful reference: [https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthena/blob/master/pyathena/**init**.py](https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthena/blob/master/pyathena/__init__.py)

Comment: What about `import pyathena.connection.Connection`?

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion could be wrong, I'm confused. Any reason why you don't want to expose it?

Comment: I think the real question is **"why don't want to expose the Connection class in your code?"**

Comment: Technically, it already **is** exposed in your code.  You access it via `pyathena.connection.Connection`.

Comment: `import pyathena.connection` will make `pyathena.connection.Connection` not error

Comment: @ReinstateMonica, I find `Connection` too mysterious to be simply left inside that code. Writing pyathena.connection.Connections makes explicit where it comes from.
Also, it is not the only "Connection" object in the code, pyathena is just one of the libs being used.

Comment: @AnthonySottile indeed. I think I can go with this. Ty a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [deferred annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/):

```
from __future__ import annotations
import pyathena


def fn(conn: pyathena.connection.Connection) -> None:
    ...
```

The annotation is effectively treated as a string literal. If you feel like that compromises type safety too much (because you could misspell the type, for instance), you can use `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` instead.

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from pyathena.connection import Connection
else:
    Connection = '...'


def fn(conn: Connection) -> None:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

How about an alias?

```
from pyathena.connection import Connection as _Con

def fn(conn: _Con):
    ...
```

Comment: Indeed it is an alternative, but I would rather keep it as `pyathena.connection.Connection`.